# Using "Step Into" when debugging does not go to class code

Tags: vb.net

I have a VS2017 solution with two projects.  One is a comclass project with a single class.  The second project is a WindowsApp project with a single form for testing the comclass.

I have set the WindowsApp to be the StartUp project of the solution.

When code in the Windows app instantiates an object in the comclass, I try to use "step into" (F11) to debug the creation of the class object but it will never enter the class code but skips over it.

If I place a break in the comclass code, it will break there and allow me to debug as expected.

I have tried removing the debug setting "just my code" with no success.
How can I get the "step into" feature work as expected?

EDIT:
I created the initial comclass project using the COM Class Template as described here [Link to COM Class Template Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/com-interop/walkthrough-creating-com-objects)

Comment: @HansPassant
  I noticed this in the Output Window: 
Step into: Stepping over property 'ComClass1.get_CustAddress'. To step into properties or operators, go to Tools->Options->Debugging and uncheck 'Step over properties and operators (Managed only)'.
It now works as expected.

Comment: You can also right-click and choose "Step into specific" and pick the particular routine that you want to step into.  This can be particularly helpful when there are other things happening on the line (e.g. parameters to the thing you want to step into that are themselves generated by a property call).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this in the Output Window:

Step into: Stepping over property 'ComClass1.get_CustAddress'. To step into properties or operators, go to Tools->Options->Debugging and uncheck 'Step over properties and operators (Managed only)'.

This works.